# BI PUBLISHER url file after installation

Tags: bi-publisher, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I installed bi publisher but didnt save url file of enterprise manager etc. thats why  i cant login to bi. my question is. where the url file saves in BI publisher installed location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed using default settings, the default port would be 9704.  The url should be

```
http://<MachineName>:9704/xmlpserver
```